# Changing the Scala version in Zeppelin

Tags: scala, apache-zeppelin

I'm using an external Jar that doesn't work properly with any version of Scala above 2.10.4. However, by looking at the Scala Jar files, I have seen that the version of Scala I'm using is 2.11. Is it possible to downgrade the Scala version to 2.10.4 without replacing the Scala Jar files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is, run from zeppelin`./dev/change_scala_version.sh 2.10`, you might need to rebuilt though using `mvn clean package -DskipTests -Pspark-2.1 -Phadoop-2.7 -Pyarn -Ppyspark -Psparkr -Pr -Pscala-2.10`